# findAndResignFirstResponder not dismissing keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have 6 `UITextFields` created in Interface Builder. After entering the values, and clicking the search button, I need to dismiss the keyboard from the view.
Currently I'm using 'findAndResignFirstResponder' and have delegates set for all text fields however the keyboard is not dismissing.

Any idea why this isn't working? Is there a better way to dismiss the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

this will resign keypad from all fields

Comment: and another option is resign all fields

Comment: i don't know why but it works on device i've testes. also sometimes on simulator too

Answer (score 0):

in the IBaction "search"

```
    [Field1 resignFirstResponder];
    [Field2 resignFirstResponder];
    [Field3 resignFirstResponder];
    [Field4 resignFirstResponder];
    [Field5 resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Field resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

You could try to **assign** a `UITextField` to the `FirstResponder` and after that to **resign** the `FirstResponder`:

```
 [someField becomeFirstResponder];
 [someField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: yes.. it is dismissing after network call is completed. why is it so?